# Missing CORS Error

Tags: javascript, cors

I realize this question is asked here at nauseum but I'm unable to find a solution to something that seems so common.

Server app is showing the following response when trying to make a post request:

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers  x-requested-with, Content-Type…accept, client-security-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods  POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin  *
Access-Control-Max-Age  1000`

but getting error:

> >
>   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/contact. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I'm trying to make the request using JS fetch function:

```
  fetch('//<my-app-server.com/endpoint>', {
    method: 'post',
    body: send_data,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
    },        
  }).then((result) => {
   console.log('success')
  }).catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error);
  })
```

I've tried with and without the headers. Using a managed apache host and just want to open up global CORS requests. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Is the remote server you're trying to fetch from set up to use CORS and does it specify your server as an allowed origin?  If your website is served from `ABC.com`, and your webpage wants to request a resource from `XYZ.com`, `XYZ.com` must explicitly give `ABC.com` permission as an allowed origin.  Setting the headers on `ABC.com` is not relevant, as it isn't a cross-origin server.

Comment: Which domain responded with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?  Was it, from your example, **my-app-server.com** or was it **localhost:3000**?

Comment: my-app-server.com responded with the above Access Control headers.

I've set the remote app server to return:

Access-Control-Allow-Headers  x-requested-with, Content-Type…accept, client-security-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods  POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin  *
Access-Control-Max-Age  1000

and the js console is showing those returned in the network tab.

Comment: Are you testing the application in Chrome? If so, it could be the CORS bug with Chrome/localhost described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

Comment: Hi @RyanGibbs, seeing the error in Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Error was related to server performing a 301 after form submission back and redirected page didn't have CORS headers.

fetch followed the page back to to redirected page and failed on CORS.